# Correct converting bytes from C++ to delphi AnsiString

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, interop, data-conversion

I have dll which accepts Pointer to array of bytes from C++ and try to move this data into AnsiString the following way

```
procedure Convert(const PByteArr: Pointer; ArrSize: Cardinal); export; cdecl;
var
  Buf: AnsiString;
begin
  SetString(Buf, PAnsiChar(PByteArr^), ArrSize);
end;
```

If I call this method from Delphi

```
procedure Try;
var
  M: TMemoryStream;
  Arr: TBytes;  
begin
  M := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    M.LoadFromFile('myfile.dat');
    SetLength(Arr, M.Size);
    M.Position := 0;
    M.Read(Arr[0], M.Size);
  finally
    M.Free;
  end;
  Convert(@Arr, Length(Arr));
end;
```

it works fine, but from c++ if gives AV on SetString.

Please help me with this.

---

From RredCat:

Let me add some explanation to Yuriy's question:
First of all about languages that we use. We need to call Delphi dll in C# project. I've created C++\CLI layer (proxy) for this purposes.
Now about C++\CLI code in header file:

```
HINSTANCE hDelphiDLL;
typedef void (*pPBDFUNC)(byte* aBytes, int size);
pPBDFUNC Convert;
```

In cpp I set Convert in constructor:

```
hDelphiDLL = LoadLibrary(<path to dll>);

if(NULL != hDelphiDLL ){
    pPBDFUNC clb= GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hDelphiDLL), "Convert");
        if(NULL != clb){
            Convert= pPBDFUNC (clb);
        }...
```

And last one method that I call from C#:

```
void Class1::Test(byte* aBytes, int size){
    Convert(aBytes,size);
}
```

Comment: 1. The `TBytes` is not needed. Just use `M.Memory` and `M.Size`. 2. As for the question itself, show us the C++. Or C#, whatever it really is.

Comment: He mentions C++ twice, and tagged it C++ so I'm changing the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Delphi code passes a pointer to pointer to array of bytes. Simplify it to use just a pointer to array of bytes:

```
procedure Convert(const PByteArr: Pointer; ArrSize: Cardinal); export; cdecl;
var
  Buf: AnsiString;
begin
  SetString(Buf, PAnsiChar(PByteArr), ArrSize);
end;
```

and call it as

```
Convert(@Arr[0], Length(Arr));
```

or

```
Convert(Pointer(Arr), Length(Arr));
```

which is the same.

Comment: The error would be easier to spot if the first parameter to `Convert` had a better type. For example, if it's a pointer to bytes, then make it `PByte`. Then it's clear that passing a `^TBytes` is wrong; the compiler will even complain about it if you do the wise thing and enabled the "typed @ operator" option.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this task much more complicated than it needs to be. C++/CLI is great when you have an existing body of C or C++ code, or a native library with a very large interface. So long as you only have a handful of functions, direct p/invoke to the native Delphi DLL is the way to go here.

Serg has already pointed out the spurious extra level of indirection in your Delphi function. So I would write the Delphi function as:

```
procedure TestFunction(Text: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
var
  Buf: AnsiString;
begin
  Buf := Text;
end;
```

On the C# side you can declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport(@"mydll.dll")]
static extern void TestFunction(string Text);
```

You can call this function from your C# code like this:

```
TestFunction("Hello");
string str = GetStringFromSomewhere();
TestFunction(str);
```

And that's it! Since at the C# end you have a string variable you can rely on the p/invoke marshaller to provide a null-terminated string to the native code. Hence there is no need to pass the length. The default calling convention for p/invoke is `stdcall` so prefer that in the Delphi code.

Comment: We had investigated both ways before started implementation. PInvoke isn't suitable for us. Because in real code we return result as PChar by reserving memory convert it to string in C++\CLI and call method which free this memory (and pass this PCHar as parameter).

Comment: You can do all that very easily with p/invoke. One trivial way would be to return a Delphi `WideString` and then use `MarshalAs` to marshal it as a `BSTR` on the managed side. That's really as easy as it gets and much easier that your C++/CLI approach.

Comment: I heard a thought that passing stings is a bad approach. Better use PChar or bytes. Is this right?

Comment: Passing string data from C# to native is trivial. Declare a parameter as `string` at the managed side and `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar` at the native side. In the other direction, `WideString`/`BSTR` is easiest. It's quite simply trivial to do and I'm sure you are grossly over-complicating this.

Comment: What about passing file as array of bytes? I need to do two things: 1) PByte to record; 2) PByte to AnsiString. As for 2, I wrote and example in my question. I still have AV when write `Move(TBytes(PArr)[0], FMyRecord, SizeOf(FMyRecord))`;
`

Comment: Well, that code is wrong. Everything you want to do is easy in pinvoke.

Comment: Could you please write an example?

Comment: I already did for the question you asked. It sounds like you are asking a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7283/discussion-between-yuriy-and-david-heffernan)